# Visual Studio Changing number of bytes for data type

Tags: c, visual-studio

Is it possible to change the number of bytes a long has in visual studio?
Currently when compiling C code sizeof(int) and sizeof(long) are both equal to 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Visual Studio, presumably your target platform (and the libraries you're using) target Windows.  The Win64 platform uses an LLP64 model (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384083.aspx) where `int` and `long` are 32-bits. It would be futile I think to try to make `long` a 64-bit type in that situation.

Use `int64_t` (from `stdint.h`) or `long long` or similar to get a 64-bit integer type

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef __int64 long;
```

That kind of nasty things.

Comment: doesn't work. You get error syaing __int64 followed by long is illegal.

Comment: Mmm, #define long __int64 :-)